# Net generic type with generic type argument

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is this possible in any other syntax???

```
interface IFoo<T<U>> where U: Bar, new() where T<U>: class, IFoo<T<U>>, new()
```

It is a way to force the generic argument for IFoo to be a generic type

```
class MyFoo<U>: IFoo<MyFoo<U>> where U: Bar, new()
```

Edited to illustrate some points:

- U is Bar... it would be a Customer entity
- T is IFoo... it would be a Customer business object
- IFoo is interface for some business objects
- IFoo defines `List<U> GetList(int compareToCustomerProperty)`

Edited to illustrate usability:

```
interface IFoo<T<U>> where U: Bar, new() where T<U>: class, IFoo<T<U>>, new()
    T<U> DoOnce();

class MyFoo<U>: IFoo<MyFoo<U>> where U: Bar, new()
    MyFoo<U> DoOnce(){return this;}
    MyFoo<U> DoAgain(){return this;}//this is not in interface

class Test{
    public Test(){
        IFoo<MyFoo<Bar>> x = new MyFoo<Bar>();//Generics can come as parameters
        x.
          DoOnce()//this is from interface
          DoAgain();//Can access this x's method cause of generic in IFoo
    }
}
```

I can currently implement it but I lose generic U.

Can  live without it??? Totally
Will I miss this approach at some point in my code??? nah!

I just came to a point where I saw this would be nice to have  in my code (method chaining between abstract & concrete, more freedom in generics)

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Why should `IFoo` care how `U` is constrained? What's the use case?

Comment: Hi @M.Babcock answered in the 4th point of the edit

Comment: Understood, but shouldn't `IFoo` delegate the responsibility of instantiating `U` to `T<U>`?

Comment: @M.Babcock I'm playing with code contracts... let me see what can I get from it

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes close to what I think you are trying to do is

```
public interface IBaz<U> 
{
}

public class Baz<U> : IBaz<U>
{
}

public interface IFoo<T, U> where T : IBaz<U> where U: Bar, new()
{
}    

public class Foo<U> : IFoo<Baz<U>, U>
    where U: Bar, new()
{
}
```

Comment: Hi @user375487 please see the relationship between IFoo & T

Comment: yes, I saw that. What you wrote is pretty much impossible though. You can't specify constraints by referring to the constrained argument and you can't implement interface which has a reference to the type you declare.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that in the .Net framework.

See it doesn't make much sense to restrain a generic type argument to being a generic itself. Consider the following type:

```
public class StringList : List<string> { }
```

`StringList` and `List<string>` are pretty much the same type. But you would be able to write

```
Foo<List<string>>
```

and not

```
Foo<StringList>
```

The fact that `List<string>` has been created from a generic type definition `List<>` is not really relevant to most of the usage unless you're working on some kind of high fly Reflection-oriented behavior.

I can see for instance that you may want this kind of features if you wanted to do something like this:

```
public interface GenericTypeConverter<T> where T : <>
{
    T<V> Convert<U,V>(T<U> thing);
}
```

If you wanted to create a Converter interface that declares functions to convert from `T<U>` to `T<V>`, for any arbitrary generic type `T`. But I can only imagine this happening if you work on complex code generation / code analysis.

And if it's the case and you really need that, you can always check at runtime if the type `T` is generic, by calling `typeof(T).IsGenericType`

Comment: Thanks @d-b I just wrote an example of what I was trying to do